# Android - How to ask for multiple permissions at a time with PermissionsDispatcher?

Tags: android, permissions

I know how to ask for multiple permissions at a time.
for example:

```
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 124;

private void insertDummyContactWrapper() {
    List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

    final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        permissionsNeeded.add("GPS");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS))
        permissionsNeeded.add("Read Contacts");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS))
        permissionsNeeded.add("Write Contacts");

    if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
        if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
            // Need Rationale
            String message = "You need to grant access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);
            showMessageOKCancel(message,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                        }
                    });
            return;
        }
        requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return;
    }

    insertDummyContact();
}

private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
    if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permissionsList.add(permission);
        // Check for Rationale Option
        if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

How i do it with [PermissionsDispatcher](http://hotchemi.github.io/PermissionsDispatcher/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy:

```
@NeedsPermission({Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS})
void insertDummyContact(){...}
```